# Angular 2 - transclude in child component

Tags: components, angular, transclusion

I've a tree-view component (which uses a tree-view-item component) and I want to let the user to define the template of the items.

something like this (which would display "Item:" followed by the name in bold) :

```
<tree-view 
    [children]="folders" 
    childrenProperty="children">
    <template>Item:<b>{{item.name}}</b></template>
</tree-view>
```

I can retrieve the `TemplateRef` using `@ContentChild` in the `TreeView` component class and access it from the `TreeViewItem` component but I've not found how to inject it into the dom of the item.

You can fin a Plunker on my tree-view component here : http://plnkr.co/edit/IMqKV4TrwHoiWfJKHHQn?p=preview

Is there a way to achieve this using Angular 2 ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `<ng-content>` tag?

Comment: `<ng-content>` can work with the ContentChild of the component, not the ContentChild of a parent component. So, I can use `<ng-content>` in the tree-view component but not in the tree-view-item component. I can maybe use it using only one component but I see other cases when using only one component will not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

After lot of digging, I've found no way to achieve exactly what I wanted.

A workaround is to load (using DynamicComponentLoader) a given component (in input) for each item of the tree.

```
<tree-view 
    [children]="folders" 
    childrenProperty="children"
    [itemComponentClass]="itemComponent">
</tree-view>
```

Where `itemComponent` is a reference to the class of the component (which have a template).

Not the better way but it's working : http://plnkr.co/edit/96IWGkw3owtUWfuG299V?p=preview